# Nextjs getting error img tag inside of div

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error i tried to solve this but I am not sure how to solve this
Here is my code I have other files too but I don't know what is the issue and why I am getting this error

```
<div
      id="default-sidebar"
      class="flex fixed flex-col w-64 h-screen px-3 py-3 bg-base font-sans overflow-y-auto mx-ato my-0 "
    >
      <div className="relative inline-block">
        <img
          src="/xpertcoin-logo-new-dark.png"
          alt="logo"
          className="w-full h-auto"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="flex flex-col justify-between flex-1 mt-12">
        <nav class="space-y-3">
          <Link
            class="rounded-md flex items-center px-3 py-2 bg-themeColor hover:bg-themecolor-100"
            href="#"
          >
            <Image
              width={16}
              height={16}
              className="align-middle"
              preview={false}
              src="/exchange.png"
              alt="icon"
            />
            <span class="ml-3 font-normal text-white text-sm">Exchanges</span>
          </Link>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

[image: I am getting this error]

Comment: where are you images stored?

Comment: public folder but if i comment images then it says div inside div

Comment: if you replace second image from next js image to standard html image(like with xpertcoin-logo-new-dark) is this error happens again?

Comment: yes error is still there at the I had to stop client-side rendering then it worked but I know its not the solution

Comment: By the way when i run your code it raises ```Error: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with `href` of `#` but only one child is supported https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children```

Comment: this error will come when client-side rendering take part like I added auth and persist the state when user login first time it works well but If i refresh the page as the state is persist so this error comes